# regex wizardry, had it and VS Code destroyed my entire Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, regex

I accidentally happened upon the regex to solve this little mystery, then my notebook blew up while working on it (thanks VS code) and I am trying to recreate it.

Sample text is this with what my regex is capturing in **BOLD**:

['03/11/2009 INDICTMENT INDICTMENT FILED. SUMMONS W/COPY OF INDICTMENT ISSUED TO LORAIN COUNTY SHERIFF. INDICTMENT FOR POSS OF DRUGS, **2925.11(A)**, F-5; DRUG PARAPHERNALIA OFFENSES, **2925.14(C)**(1), M-4; POSS OF DRUGS, **2925.11(A)**, M-M'], ["03/16/2009 RETURN SHERIFF'S RETURN - I MADE RESIDENCE SERVICE ON DEFENDANT ON: 3/12/09 , PHIL R. STAMMITTI, SHERIFF"], ['03/19/2009 ARRAIGNMENT DEFENDANT ARRAIGNED. WAIVED READING OF INDICTMENT, ENTERED PLEA OF NOT GUILTY. BOND CONTINUED.   **2901.07 AND SHALL NOT BE RELEASED UNTIL A SUITABLE DNA SPECIMEN HAS BEEN COLLECTED.'], ['12/15/2016 BOND BOND POSTED: $4,000 SURETY BOND POSTED BY JC BAIL BONDS (AMERICAN)**']

My intent is to capture all the revised code sections (example formats of those below) occurring after the phrase "INDICTMENT FILED" up to the first "]" that occurs afterward.  Problem is, the revised code sections can have these various formats:

```
2913.1, 2913.12, 2913.123, 2913.1234, 2913.1(A), 2913.12(A)(1)
```

Plus, my current regex which does grab the numbers of the revised code sections, is not grabbing the parenthetical content in all its varieties (I have boldfaced what my regex below is currently matching) and is, unfortunately, grabbing the second boldfaced section (which I do NOT want).  I need the first time the phrase "INDICTMENT FILED" is listed, and all the revised code sections following that phrase in that string until a "]" is found and then stop matching.

Here is my regex so far and it is not completely working.  I had this worked out and it was matching only what I wanted, then, you know, computers and not backing up every 30 seconds, and blammo, here I am.  My regex:

```
(\d{4}\.\d{1,4}.*?\))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there! The problem with your regex was that after `\d{1,4}`, it matches `.*?` = *anything* until it sees a `)`. When there's nothing in parentheses after `2901.07`, it matches everything until the next `)` at the end of `AMERICAN)`.

Here's what I came up with:

`\d{4}\.\d{2}(?:\(\w+\))*`

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/FBjGd7/5)

Explanation:

- `\d{4}\.\d{1,4}`: 4 numbers, period, 1-4 numbers (you had this part)
- `(?: ... )*`: `*` = Zero or more of this group. `?:` means don't capture it as a numbered group
- `\(\w+\)`: Literal `(` followed by 1 or more word characters, followed by a literal `)`